# Escape from When-Statement (like continue or break) in Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, control-flow

I have a piece of code as follows:

```
when {
        dateFrom == null && dateTo == null -> Unit
        dateFrom != null -> params["lastUpdated"] = "$dateFrom,"
        dateTo != null -> params["lastUpdated"] = ",$dateTo"
        else -> params["lastUpdated"] = "$dateFrom,$dateTo"
    }
```

Can I escape the `when` in a manner like `continue` in a loop?

I'm now using `dateFrom == null && dateTo == null -> Unit` but that's not very elegant. (`dateFrom == null && dateTo == null -> True` is also possible, but likewise, not very elegant)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `else` part will never succeed, because 1 of the 1st 3 conditions will be `true`.
So your code is equivalent to this:

```
when {
    dateFrom == null && dateTo == null -> Unit
    dateFrom != null -> params["lastUpdated"] = "$dateFrom,"
    dateTo != null -> params["lastUpdated"] = ",$dateTo"
}
```

and finally this:

```
when {
    dateFrom != null -> params["lastUpdated"] = "$dateFrom,"
    dateTo != null -> params["lastUpdated"] = ",$dateTo"
    else -> Unit
}
```

I think that maybe you wanted to have:

```
when {
    dateFrom != null && dateTo != null -> params["lastUpdated"] = "$dateFrom,$dateTo"
    dateFrom != null -> params["lastUpdated"] = "$dateFrom,"
    dateTo != null -> params["lastUpdated"] = ",$dateTo"
}
```

If this is what you wanted then there is no case of further simplification.

Comment: Is the else even needed?

Comment: For the case that both are null then the OP wants to return explicitly `Unit`

Comment: I think the point of the question is that the OP doesn't want to return `Unit`. He wants to get rid of that, like you would skip an iteration in a loop by using `continue`.

Comment: If this is the case then the else can be omitted.

Answer (score 4):

There's no direct way to do this. As an alternative to just returning `Unit`, which looks fine in this case, you can wrap the `when` statement in a scoping inline function call, like [`run { ... }`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/run.html), and [use a `return@label`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/returns.html#return-at-labels):

```
run { 
    when {
        dateFrom == null && dateTo == null -> return@run
        /* ... */
    }
}
```

This construct may be more useful if the `when` branches are more complex than a single statement.

Comment: I think `when` should also work with labels. This is the best solution to fix this for now.

Answer (score 1):

If you rewrite your conditions you can get rid of the case where you now have `Unit`

```
when {
    dateFrom != null && dateTo != null -> params["lastUpdated"] = "$dateFrom,$dateTo"
    dateFrom != null                   -> params["lastUpdated"] = "$dateFrom,"
    dateTo != null                     -> params["lastUpdated"] = ",$dateTo"
}
```